# Problemas de encoding no console do eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, codificação-de-caracteres

Ao ler o conteúdo de um arquivo para imprimir o mesmo no console do eclipse, tenho uma palavra acentuada e a mesma está saindo assim no console:

```
Ã© um teste
```

O correto de mostrar é:

```
é um teste
```

Eu conferi as opções de Run do eclipse e o meu *encoding* está **ISO-8859-1**

Como posso resolver?

Para teste, estou usando o seguinte código pra fazer a ação:

```
final Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/home/douglas/teste.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
           System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
```

Comment: Tem como você colocar em UTF-8?

Comment: Funcionou @VictorStafusa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode especificar o encoding correto no [construtor do do `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-):

```
final Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/home/douglas/teste.txt"), "ISO-8859-1");

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

No entanto, recomendo sempre usar o *encoding* UTF-8 que em tese funcionaria com quaisquer caracteres em qualquer lugar do mundo desde que tudo seja codificado nele. O ISO-8859-1 e outros *encoding* semelhantes têm características mais regionais, criando com isso problemas de portabilidade.

Quando o arquivo de entrada estiver no UTF-8, você faria então isso:

```
final Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/home/douglas/teste.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

O construtor sem o *encoding/charset* depende da codificação padrão da plataforma, e por causa disso, sofre com problemas de portabilidade como esse.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.